# Creating a list from list of a list in python

Tags: python, nlp, text-mining

I am creating a tree-like structure where every leaf node has 5 documents to it. To get the document of parent node all the documents of the child will be assigned to it.

For e.g. A is the parent node and B, C are child nodes both of whom have 5 documents each. So, the documents for A will be 5+5=10. Similarly, the parent of A will get 10 documents of A + no of a document of the sibling of A. We will repeat this until we reach the root node.

I want to store documents of A as a list of size 10 and similarly parent of A as total no of documents of their child. But it is storing it as a list of size 2 and under each list, there are 5 documents each. And the parent of A is also storing documents of A as a list of 3 not `3*5=15` what I want.

How can I store the document at each node as total no of documents and not a list of lists?
Below is the code which I am using.

```
from anytree import Node, RenderTree
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

class Node(Node):
    Node.documents = None
    Node.vector = None

### Creating tree by giving documnets to leaf ###
### Tree Creation ###    
# L1    
Finance = Node("Finance")
# L2
Credit_and_Lending = Node("Credit and Lending", parent=Finance)
# L3
Credit_Cards = Node("Credit Cards", parent=Credit_and_Lending)

Loans = Node("Loans", parent=Credit_and_Lending)

# L4
Low_Interest_and_No_Interest_Credit_Cards = Node("Low Interest & No Interest Credit Cards", parent=Credit_Cards, documents=[(fvc.loc[(fvc['keyword']=='low interest & no interest credit cards') & (fvc['organic_rank']==1)])['vocab'].tolist()[0]
                            , (fvc.loc[(fvc['keyword']=='low interest & no interest credit cards') & (fvc['organic_rank']==2)])['vocab'].tolist()[0]
                            , (fvc.loc[(fvc['keyword']=='low interest & no interest credit cards') & (fvc['organic_rank']==3)])['vocab'].tolist()[0]
                            , (fvc.loc[(fvc['keyword']=='low interest & no interest credit cards') & (fvc['organic_rank']==4)])['vocab'].tolist()[0]
                            , (fvc.loc[(fvc['keyword']=='low interest & no interest credit cards') & (fvc['organic_rank']==5)])['vocab'].tolist()[0]])

Rewards_Cards = Node("Rewards Cards", parent=Credit_Cards, documents=[(fvc.loc[(fvc['keyword']=='rewards cards') & (fvc['organic_rank']==1)])['vocab'].tolist()[0]
                            , (fvc.loc[(fvc['keyword']=='rewards cards') & (fvc['organic_rank']==2)])['vocab'].tolist()[0]
                            , (fvc.loc[(fvc['keyword']=='rewards cards') & (fvc['organic_rank']==3)])['vocab'].tolist()[0]
                            , (fvc.loc[(fvc['keyword']=='rewards cards') & (fvc['organic_rank']==4)])['vocab'].tolist()[0]
                            , (fvc.loc[(fvc['keyword']=='rewards cards') & (fvc['organic_rank']==5)])['vocab'].tolist()[0]])

Student_Credit_Cards = Node("Student Credit Cards", parent=Credit_Cards, documents=[(fvc.loc[(fvc['keyword']=='student credit cards') & (fvc['organic_rank']==1)])['vocab'].tolist()[0]
                            , (fvc.loc[(fvc['keyword']=='student credit cards') & (fvc['organic_rank']==2)])['vocab'].tolist()[0]
                            , (fvc.loc[(fvc['keyword']=='student credit cards') & (fvc['organic_rank']==3)])['vocab'].tolist()[0]
                            , (fvc.loc[(fvc['keyword']=='student credit cards') & (fvc['organic_rank']==4)])['vocab'].tolist()[0]
                            , (fvc.loc[(fvc['keyword']=='student credit cards') & (fvc['organic_rank']==5)])['vocab'].tolist()[0]])

Auto_Financing = Node("Auto Financing", parent=Loans, documents=[(fvc.loc[(fvc['keyword']=='auto financing') & (fvc['organic_rank']==1)])['vocab'].tolist()[0]
                            , (fvc.loc[(fvc['keyword']=='auto financing') & (fvc['organic_rank']==2)])['vocab'].tolist()[0]
                            , (fvc.loc[(fvc['keyword']=='auto financing') & (fvc['organic_rank']==3)])['vocab'].tolist()[0]
                            , (fvc.loc[(fvc['keyword']=='auto financing') & (fvc['organic_rank']==4)])['vocab'].tolist()[0]
                            , (fvc.loc[(fvc['keyword']=='auto financing') & (fvc['organic_rank']==5)])['vocab'].tolist()[0]])
Commercial_Lending = Node("Commercial Lending", parent=Loans, documents=[(fvc.loc[(fvc['keyword']=='commercial lending') & (fvc['organic_rank']==1)])['vocab'].tolist()[0]
                            , (fvc.loc[(fvc['keyword']=='commercial lending') & (fvc['organic_rank']==2)])['vocab'].tolist()[0]
                            , (fvc.loc[(fvc['keyword']=='commercial lending') & (fvc['organic_rank']==3)])['vocab'].tolist()[0]
                            , (fvc.loc[(fvc['keyword']=='commercial lending') & (fvc['organic_rank']==4)])['vocab'].tolist()[0]
                            , (fvc.loc[(fvc['keyword']=='commercial lending') & (fvc['organic_rank']==5)])['vocab'].tolist()[0]])

##### Visualizing the created tree #####
for pre, fill, node in RenderTree(Finance):
    print("%s%s" % (pre, node.name))

##### Getting documents for parent nodes #####
def get_documents(node):    
    if node.documents is not None:
        return node.documents
    else:
        child_nodes = node.children
        lis = []
        for child in child_nodes:
            child_docs = get_documents(child)
            lis.append(child_docs)
        node.documents = lis
        return lis


get_documents(Finance)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this syntax:

```
lis = lis + child_docs
```

Instead of

```
 lis.append(child_docs)
```